# GitLab unable to push to master branch

Tags: git, gitlab

Getting this error when I push:

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I've checked out the problem online and people mentioned about unprotecting the branch by going to the repository settings.

I've went there and it shows this message:

`There are currently no protected branches, protect a branch with the form above.`

I have no protected branch? If the `master` branch is really protected then how to make it `unprotected` when there's no `protected` branches. No buttons to click..

Any solution?

EDIT:

The repository is a group project, so by default everyone in the group is given access as Developers.

I want `Developers` to be able to push to the `master` branch for now.
So how to make the master branch unprotected?

Answer (score 1):

You can't is protected by default as @[hamed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531130/hamed) said

change role from `Developer` to `Master` you need `root` access

Comment: What if I want `Developer` to push to the `master` branch? How do I make the `master` branch unprotected?

Comment: you can disable this protection from your project refer to this : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/40

Comment: That is from 2 years ago. My issue is that I can't see the list of unprotected branches. Here's where I went: `Project => Settings => Repository => Protected Branches`. It shows that there are currently no unprotected branches.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

It seems that I can't see the protected `master` branch when the repository is empty.

`Developers` can't push to an empty repository since the `master` branch is not visible in the list of protected branches when the repository is empty, so you can't change the `master` branch to `unprotected` until you push the initial base project online.

So I had to push using an account that has the `master` or `owner` access.

Hope this helps anyone out there!